# how to pass an array of numbers with typescript and react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm using Types in React for the first time and I'm not very familiar with it.

I'm trying to add numbers from a form in a child component to an array of numbers.

Therefor I have created a useState hook:

```
const [valuesList, setValuesList] = useState<number[]>([]);
```

Now I'm trying to pass the setValuesList hook to the child component:

```
<AddNum
        setValues={setValuesList}
      />
```

In the child component I'm defining an interface for the props:

```
interface AppProps {
  setValues: (value: number) => void;
}
```

However when I try to call the setValues hook:

```
const addNumber = (value: string): undefined => {
const num = parseInt(value);
props.setValues((prevList) => prevList.concat(num));
return undefined;
```

};

I'm getting this error in the parent component:

```
/Users/acandael/Tutorials/react/add-nums/src/components/AddNum.tsx
TypeScript error in /Users/acandael/Tutorials/react/add-nums/src/components/AddNum.tsx(21,21):
Argument of type '(prevList: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'.
  Type '(prevList: any) => any' is missing the following properties from type 'number[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 27 more.  TS2345

    19 |   const addNumber = (value: string): undefined => {
    20 |     const num = parseInt(value);
  > 21 |     props.setValues((prevList) => prevList.concat(num));
       |                     ^
    22 |     return undefined;
    23 |   };
    24 |
```

Does anyone know how I can add numbers from a child component to an array of numbers in the parent component, and keep TypeScript happy?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is `num`? Is that a number or an array of numbers?

Comment: @RameshReddy num is a number

Comment: Did you change the interface as in my updated answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to change the state value of an array of numbers **to a number** by calling `props.setValue(num)`.

Also the type definition for `setValues` in interface `AppProps` is incorrect. TS will infer the type of the setter function `setValuesList` as `React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<number[]>>` which is incompatible with the type `(value: number) => void`.

The correct definition for the `setValues` function would be **if you want to pass the function `setValuesList` as props.**

```
interface AppProps {
   setValues: React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<number[]>>
 
   // setValues: (numArr: number[]) => void  ( this will work as well )
}
```

The solution for updating the state value of `valuesList` would be to either use functional update or to create another callback function that receives a `number` as argument and updates the state.

**With functional update**

```
setValues(prev => prev.concat(num))
```

**With `setValues` as a different callback function**

```
// with this solution you don't need to modify the interface AppProps

interface AppProps {
   setValues: (num: number) => void
}

const Foo: React.FC<AppProps> = ({ setValues }) => {
  
  // component logic
  
  return (
   <>
   </>
  )
}

// in parent component
const [valuesList, setValuesList] = useState<number[]>([])

const updateWithNewValue = useCallback((num: number) => {
   setValuesList(prev => prev.concat(num))
}, [])

// pass the updateWithNewValue as props

<Foo setValues={updateWithNewValue}/>
```

*A similar example in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-hofstadter-g1w6x?file=/src/index.tsx)*

Comment: thanks @subashMahapatra, I tried to implement your sollution with callback function, but then I get this error message:
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: That could be the result of how you call the `setValues` function inside the component.

Comment: I'm calling the setValues function like this:
const addNumber = (value: string): undefined => {
    const num = parseInt(value);
    props.setValues(num);
    return undefined;
  };

Comment: Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-hofstadter-g1w6x?file=/src/index.tsx) with everything working. Try to edit the sandbox with a minimal example of the issue.

Comment: thanks @subashMahapatra, I found the issue. Should have called my addNumber function like this:
onClick={() => addNumber(props.value)}